# Specifying Maximum Column Width When Loading Flat File

Tags: apache-spark

I am loading a file that has many columns that exceed 1000+ characters (in some cases 4000-8000 characters) and am receiving this error when I query the resulting dataframe from loading it from the file:

> FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/fin/fm/spynotesandcommentsfile.txt
> Caused by: TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - null
> Caused by: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

In the reader, I can specify options (`.option("option",true)`) and have been looking for an option to allow for the maximum width possible for all columns since the resulting dataframe cannot be queried. The *actual reader* needs to allow for maximum width here for every column loaded into the dataframe from the file, which is why many of the solutions about many columns (not the issue) or growing a dataframe (not the issue) don't solve this issue.

```
val spyfile = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("maximumColumnWidthAllowed", true) ///if this existed or a similar option
```

I was able to confirm that one field on one of the rows in a file has a character length of 12,043.  It still fails for the same reason if I specify `.option("maxCharsPerColumn", -1` or `.option("maxCharsPerColumn", "-1")`

Comment: try setting `maxCharsPerColumn` to `-1`?

Comment: Tested `.option("maxCharsPerColumn", "-1")` and `.option("maxCharsPerColumn", -1)` and still get the same error when selecting all columns from the dataframe.